# How can I make a paragraph bounce around in a div?

Tags: javascript, html

This just for fun to see if Javascript can do it.

Imagine I have a paragraph, and surrounding it, is a div or a table cell.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td><p class="bouncer">This is the bouncing paragraph.</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Using Javascript, how would I make this object bounce? Not just up and down, but the whole x and y axis movement. It would move diagonally until reaching the edge then come back and bounce realistically within the 'box'.

Is this possible? Again: This is just for fun, I'm not going to put it on a website and reproduce the whole Marquee debacle.

Comment: plain js or through some useful fw/libs like jQuery/mootools/etc ?

Comment: @stecb I guess using a library like jQuery it is not a really big challenge :).

Comment: I swear to god if I find out you do this on a website I see I will destroy your computer with thermite :)

Comment: @bazmegakapa maybe it's not about the 'challenge', but about gettin' things done quickly :D ..that's why I asked him :)

Comment: What's wrong with using the good old `<blink>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up - but remember my warning :)

http://jsfiddle.net/He5aQ/2/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible.

The easiest way is to use jQuery's [`.animate()` method](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and manipulate the `top` and `left` properties.

You can also try with plain Javascript, playing with `position: relative` or `position: absolute`, and manipulating `top` and `left` with `setTimeout` calls.

I just gave you an outline because you said it is for fun, so I guess you might want to solve this yourself. It is possible, so go on and have fun :).